# Trouble running Eclipse project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, git, swing, intellij-idea

[image: IntelliJ printscreen]

I have created a project in Eclipse, where the main entry point is a JFrame. I have then exported this project to GitHub and cloned the repository for use in IntelliJ. However, when trying to run the project in IntelliJ, it cannot detect the JFrame extension as a main entry point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave this for posterity but it was a stupid question and a stupid mistake. I hadn't set the source path in the project.